# How to Pass Callback argument for Win32 Dll api from C# function?

Tags: c#

1. WIN32 funciton to call from C#:

   ```
   int PTSetGUICallbacks (  
     IN int hConnection,
     IN void *pGuiStreamingCallbackCtx,
     IN PT_GUI_STATE_CALLBACK pfnGuiStateCallback,
     IN void *pGuiStateCallbackCtx
   )
   ```
2. Win32 Callback function prototype "PT_GUI_STATE_CALLBACK":

   ```
   int PT_STD_GUI_STATE_CALLBACK (
     IN DWORD dwGuiState,
     OUT BYTE *pbyResponse,
     IN DWORD dwMessage
   )
   ```
3. My C# function for to call the above Win32 function inside i am passing C# function as a callback to that Win32 function:

   ```
   public void SetCallback() 
   {
     var callback_delegate = new PT_GUI_STATE_CALLBACK(GUI_STATE_CALLBACK);            
     GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(callback_delegate);
     IntPtr intptr_delegate =
       Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback_delegate);       
     int mErrorCode = PTSetGUICallbacks(mDevHandle, IntPtr.Zero, intptr_delegate,  IntPtr.Zero);       
     gch.Free(); 
    }
   ```

this code doesnot work, i mean i am not getting callback from win32 api to my C# method (`GUI_STATE_CALLBACK`)

So now i need to pass that callback to the win32 api from my C# function.

Anyone know the answer?

4. PInvoke Function declaration for WIN32 api:

   public static extern int PTSetGUICallbacks(int ahConnection,
        IntPtr aStreamingcbCtx, IntPtr aGuiStateCb, IntPtr aGuiStateCbCtx);

Any update on this?

Is any other alternative way is there to do this?

Comment: Can't get your code to match up at the moment - in 1) you show a function with 4 parameters, in 3) same function is called with 5.

Comment: Thanks damien, i am very sorry, Wrongly i have typed, i have changed now. please look in to it. Thanks

Comment: Just based on the naming, I have a hunch that you shouldn't be calling `gch.Free()` immediately after calling `PTSetGUICallbacks` - that sounds like it's registering some kind of function that may be called well after the `PTSetGUICallbacks` function has returned - in which case you need to keep the GCHandle alive for as long as callbacks might occur - presumably until you "unset" the callback or shut down whatever might use that callback. Whether that's *the* issue though, I can't tell (and as I say, this is just a guess based on the naming)

Answer (score 1):

Define your CallBack function as "CallBack"

```
public static extern int PTSetGUICallbacks(
int ahConnection,IntPtr aStreamingcbCtx, 
CallBack aGuiStateCb, IntPtr aGuiStateCbCtx);
```

Calling it:

```
CallBack cb = new CallBack(GuiCBFunction);
PTSetGUICallbacks(mDevHandle, IntPtr.Zero, cb,  IntPtr.Zero);
```

The Callback in c#:

```
int GuiCBFunction (UInt32 dwGuiState, IntPtr pbyResponse, UInt32 dwMessage )
```

example for "CallBack": http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a95009h1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I have tried it before but its too not working. I am not getting the call in my C# callback function. Is any other way there to try?

Comment: is there a errorCode returned ? maybe with the Connection Handle something is wrong. Do you got / Can Enable any Debug Log from the Software (from with you are using the API) that logs wheter the CallBack is called or not ?

Comment: A other way would be to write a C++ CLI ClassLibrary Wrapper for it.